# How to store image in local storage not path?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can we store image in local storage and get the image from the storage. As We store number or string in local storage can we store image not path ?
http://jsfiddle.net/sAH8w/

```
$(function(){
    $('#save').click(function(){
        alert('save')   
        localStorage.setItem("image", https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/t2ywui846zp58ye/plus_minus_icons.png?m=);
    })

    $('#get').click(function(){
        alert('get');
        var image=localStorage.getItem("image");   
    })
})
```

Comment: You should probably look into base64 encoding the image and the saving it as a string in localstorage.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get image data in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript)

Comment: Seconding @springbo. You should read into size limits too - in my (admittedly out-of-date and limited experience) I found that local storage filled up pretty quickly (and capacity varied a bit between browsers). Some associated reading here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989284/what-is-the-max-size-of-localstorage-values

Comment: Hope This helps

stackoverflow.com/questions/19183180/how-to-upload-an-image-save-it-to-localstorage-and-then-display-it-on-the-next

Comment: why it is not working http://jsfiddle.net/sAH8w/2/

Comment: any solutionof this Question

Answer (score 1):

> You can make use of "canvas" element.
>
> // Get a reference to the image element
>
> var elephant = document.getElementById("elephant");   // Take action
>   when the image has loaded
>
> elephant.addEventListener("load", function () {
>
> var imgCanvas = document.createElement("canvas"),
>           imgContext = imgCanvas.getContext("2d");
>
> ```
> // Make sure canvas is as big as the picture
> imgCanvas.width = elephant.width;
> imgCanvas.height = elephant.height;
>
> // Draw image into canvas element
> imgContext.drawImage(elephant, 0, 0, elephant.width, elephant.height);
>
> // Get canvas contents as a data URL
> var imgAsDataURL = imgCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
>
> // Save image into localStorage
> try {
>     localStorage.setItem("elephant", imgAsDataURL);
> }
> catch (e) {
>     console.log("Storage failed: " + e);
> } }, false);
> ```

Comment: can you use fiddle..I added the image in fiddle external source

Comment: As reviewed code on jsfiddle.net/sAH8w/2, you have made mistakes in formatting of code, due to which when javascript loads, it does not load properly, thus prohibiting execution of your scripts.

Comment: $(function(){
    $('#save').click(function(){
        
alert('save');
        alert(getBase64Image("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/t2ywui846zp58ye/plus_minus_icons.png?m="));

    });
    
   $('#get').click(function(){
        
        alert('get');
            var image=localStorage.getItem("image");
          
    });
    
});

Comment: please provinde fiddle

Comment: I have made the cahnges on fiddle andits working. You need to change it as per your requirement.

Comment: but where is that fiddle